# Using XML Web Service with VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2010

Ok! I just created a VB.Net project and added web reference for other company's XML web service. Let's name the web reference as "WebRef". They have provided the web service layout and there is a function named "GetServiceTicketList". It requires "UserID", "UserPassword", and "ServiceTicketNumber".

I am trying to get a service ticket list on datagrid with "GetServiceTicketList".

When I do this, then I get a error "Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String' from "ls_ParamValue"

```
Public Function GetTicketList(ByVal strXMLin As String) As String
   Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("GetServiceTicketList", New Object() {strXMLin})
   Return CType(results(0),String)
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

  Dim Client As WebRef.service1 = New WebRef.service1
  Dim XMLResoponse As String
  Dim UserId As String = "SuperMan"
  Dim UserPW As String = "Batman"
  Dim Version As String = "1234"
  Dim ls_ParamValue As String()
  ls_ParamValue = {UserId, UserPW, Version}
  XMLResoponse = Client.GetServiceTicketList(ls_ParamValue)

End Sub
```

Comment: @Hoorayo: your edit doesn't change anything. You're still passing an array where a single string is expected.

Comment: "GetServiceTicketList" requires three input parameters which are "UserId", "UserPW", and "Version". But the function takes only a single string. How do I do it?

Comment: @Hoorayo: you don't. There's obviously something wrong here. The proxy generated by using "Add Web Reference" only gives it a single parameter. Are you _sure_ it takes three? Can you post that part of the WSDL?

Comment: @John. You are right and it is a string value, "strXMLin". But I just found out "strXMLin" is a XML Tag. I have to create "strXMLin" with those three input parameter. I thought I just need to pass those three parameter, but I need to pass a string as XML Tag. I just need to figure out how to convert those three parameter as XML Tag. Let me know if you have a tutorial link.

Comment: @Hoorayo: post the XML that is expected, and I can show you how to create it.

Comment: This is the XML tag that needs to be generated. By the way, those elements come from SQL server.
<rootdoc><UserID>Hello</UserID><Password>WorldPassword</Password><Company>AABB</Company><Name>CCDD</Name><ServiceTicketNumber>12345</ServiceTicketNumber></rootdoc>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is declared to take a single string as a parameter. You are passing it an array of strings.